# I want to design of page of my GWT web application like windows 8 design

Tags: java, gwt, windows-8

May be this is silly question. I have no Idea but I am trying.I have done Google and had been through lots of example. But still didn't find a nice solution for Main page.

I am developing a GWT web application. I want to change the design of main page of my GWT web application like windows 8 design. Since I am using GWT so I can't use C# here. only HTML, JAVA CSS or JS. Is it possible?

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

You can make your GWT app look any way you like it. The look of your app is created using HTML and CSS. It does not depend on JavaScript, GWT or any other library that drives the behavior of an app.

Comment: Thanks.. I am not very much familiar windows8 design, what they have used... I have used for my main page CSS3 and now it working for me, but I have now Idea how the one cell splits into more cells.. If you know about windows8 HTML design cells or any links will be appreciated. Thanks again